# HttpPostedFileBase - Trazendo null quando tenho muitos arquivos com o nome grande

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Bom dia Amigos seguinte

Tenho um sistema web mvc com c# e preciso realizar o upload de diversos arquivos simultaneamente. Ate ai, tudo bem, porém quando os arquivos tem um nome grande da problema vou exemplificar.

Tenho 5000 xmls para serem importados
com o nome "NFe35160870940994008196550100004554491586403310.xml"

quando seleciono 10 ate 20 arquivos todos vão para o controler, agora acima disso vai null.

Agora quando troco o nome do arquivo para "A" ficando A(1), A(2)... consegio enviar para o controler mais ate 2000 de uma vez.

Não sei mais oque fazer, ja aumente o maxRequestLength para o maximo

segue abiaxo o codigo que uso
CSHTML

```html
 @using (Html.BeginForm("ImportarXML", "LeituraNfe", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label>Selecione arquivos para importação</label><br />
            <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="postedFilesBases" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label></label><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Importar" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Controller

```js
public ActionResult ImportarXML(List<HttpPostedFileBase> postedFilesBases)
{
    try
    {
        var h = new List<XmlDocument>();
        foreach (var item in postedFilesBases)
        {
            var document = new XmlDocument();
            document.Load(item.InputStream);
            h.Add(document);
        }
  postedFilesBases.Clear();
  foreach (var item in h)
  {
   //Faça algo
  }
 }
 cath(Exception ex)
 {
  //erro
 }
}
```

Comment: Usando o fiddler ou outra ferramenta semelhante, você verificou se o seu post está indo inteiro ou corrompendo / truncando?

Comment: Leando, não testei com eles não só consigo ver que no controller vem null

Comment: use IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>

Comment: Pesquisando encontrei isso https://weblogs.asp.net/hosamkamel/resolving-maximum-request-length-exceeded-exception parace que existe um tamanho maximo no request, espero que ajude.

Comment: Ola resolvi o problema apenas trocando para subir o Diretorio completo ao invez dos arquivos indivuais

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ola resolvi o problema apenas trocando para subir o Diretorio completo ao invez dos arquivos indivuais veja abaixo como ficou o trecho  do codigo repare na linha comentada que era antes e agora como esta

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("ImportarXML", "LeituraNfe", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label>Selecione arquivos para importação</label><br />
            <input type="file" name="postedFilesBases" directory mozdirectory webkitdirectory/>
            @*<input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="postedFilesBases" />*@
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label></label><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Importar" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```